Connecting to ATT, I get "CTRL-EVENT-EAP-FAILURE EAP authentication failed"
When I connect with OpenWRT to ATT GPON and try to EAPOL auth with wpa_supplicant, I get the following error,
CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started
CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=13
CTRL-EVENT-EAP-METHOD EAP vendor 0 method 13 (TLS) selected
CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-CERT depth=1 subject='/C=US/O=ATT Services Inc/CN=ATT Services Inc Enhanced Services CA'
CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-CERT depth=0 subject='/C=US/ST=Texas/L=Dallas/O=AT&T Services, Inc./CN=foo.bar.sbcglobal.net'
CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-ALT depth=0 DNS:foo.bar.sbcglobal.net
CTRL-EVENT-EAP-FAILURE EAP authentication failed

How can I resolve this error?

I had wpad-wolfssl. And, I needed wpad-openssl
opkg remove wpad-wolfssl
opkg add wpad-openssl

Then it worked..
10g-2: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
10g-2: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-SUCCESS EAP authentication completed successfully
10g-2: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to MACADDR completed [id=0 id_str=]
no PHY for ifname 10g-2

